# Tomcat cannot get servlets to work

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

i'm having problem with adding a servlet to my project .
I have create a new project webapp in eclipse ee using maven .
this is the directory tree i got :

```
Deployment Descriptor.
|
JavaScript Resources
|
Deployed Resources
|
Java Resources .
   |
    Libraries
   |
    src/main/resources
        |
         com
            |
             saeedh
                   |
                    servlets
                           |
                            start
                                 |
                                  Login.java
   |
    src
       |
        main
            |
             webapp
                   |
                    index.jsp
                   |
                    register.jsp
                   |
                    css
                   |
                    WEB-INF
                           |
                            web.xml
            |
             resources
                     |
                     com
                        |
                        saeedh
                              |
                               servlets
                                       |
                                       start
                                            |
                                             Login.java
```

my web.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.saeedh.servlets.start.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

</web-app>
```

my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.saeedh</groupId>
  <artifactId>SocialNetwork</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SocialNetwork Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Restlet repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.restlet.com</url>
        </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <finalName>SocialNetwork</finalName>
      <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Login servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (request.getParameter("register") != null) {
            response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
        }
        else if (request.getParameter("login") != null) {

        }

    }

}
```

in index.jsp , i have two submit buttons one with value="register" and the other with value="login".
if i run the project above , i get the main page which is index.jsp, but if i click on register/login button i get the error :
**HTTP Status 404 - /SocialNetwork/Login**
if i add mapping in servlet :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

i get the error :
**HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.test.Test**

also i have noticed that i don't get compiled servlets (.class) files in any of the directories , what am i doing wrong ?

**NOTE:**
i found a lot of problems getting servlets to work but none matched my tree directory or i've tried the solution sugested and didn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Servlet Java source shouldn't be under `src/main/resources`, move it to `src/main/java`. If you have any properties files, or resource bundles, or other external resource files that you need to read from the Servlet (or other Java code); those would go in `src/main/resources` (unless it's for *testing*; then `src/test/resoures` or `src/test/java`, for testing code).